# Why does instantiating XmlSerializer before ServiceHost.Open is called produce a memory & handle leak

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, xml-serialization

When looking for a memory- and handleleak in a .NET/WCF/Windows Service I noticed strange behavior that I cannot explain.
Here the setup and the resolution. What I am looking for would be an explanation for the observed behavior.

I installed a Windows Service.

I started the service.

I called a simple method with a transactional WCF call (new channel per call - no caching).

For each call about 2 handles remain in memory.

This can be observed if the following items are applicable:

1. It is a Windows Service; don't run it as a Console App.
2. Use a Transaction (separate process or machine tested only) to call the WCF method.
3. Before calling `ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);` instantiate XmlSerializer with some type.
4. The type is a custom type. It does not occur with `new XmlSerializer(typeof(string))` or new `XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument))`. No call to serialize is necessary. It is enough if the custom type has only a string as property (no handles anywhere!)
5. Creating a static XmlSerialization.dll using i.e. SGen.exe will not produce this problem.

My Code already includes the fix:

Use XmlSerializer *earliest* in OnStart():

**Program.cs**

```
WindowsService winSvc = new WindowsService();
ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]{winSvc};                    
ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
```

**WindowsService.cs**

```
internal sealed class WindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost wcfServiceHost = null;

    internal WindowsService()
    {
        AutoLog = true;
        CanStop = true;
        CanShutdown = true;
        CanPauseAndContinue = false;
    }

    internal void StartWcfService()
    {
        wcfServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DemoService));
        wcfServiceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (wcfServiceHost != null)
        {
            wcfServiceHost.Close();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));

        StartWcfService();
    }
}
```

**DemoService.cs**

```
[ServiceBehavior
    (
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
        TransactionAutoCompleteOnSessionClose = false,
        IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
    )
]
public sealed class DemoService : IDemoService
{           
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**Client.cs**:

```
IChannelFactory<IDemoService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDemoService>("defaultClientConfiguration");
IDisposable channel = null;
for (int index = 0; index < 5000; index++)
{
    using
    (
        channel = (IDisposable)channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:23456/DemoService")))
        {                       
        IDemoService demoService = (IDemoService)channel;
        using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            demoService.Add(3, 9);
            tx.Complete();  
        }
    )
}
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Please note, I'm not interested in finding a way to avoid the leak (I already know how to do this) but in an explanation (i.e. WHY is it happening).

Comment: "It does not occur with new XmlSerializer<string>() or new XmlSerializer<XmlDocument>()"  Does this mean your custom type is leaking a handle?  Does it use something with handle and does it implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: No, you can create a new Type with just a string property and it will also leak. Also notice, I'm not instantiating my type, just the serializer with the type.

Comment: I note wcfServiceHost is IDisposable but you only Close it?

Comment: I Close it and then Dispose it. And even if there was a wrong implementation at this point, this is clearly not the problem.

Comment: I don't see a call to wcfServiceHost.Dispose

Comment: This is exactly from example from msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: I'm having difficulty reproducing the problem with the above code - to where do I move the creation of the XmlSerializer to reproduce it (as you mentioned it was moved to fix the problem)?

Comment: i.e. in a static variable of WindowsService class. If I remember correctly also in Program.cs before ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun); or also in Constructor of WindowsService. Every piece of code that is run before the OnStart method of WindowsService.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think some of the inner workings do this question justice. I do this from the back of my head, since I ran into this problem as well some time ago, and it took me a day to track back including extensive use of Reflector and ANTS Memory profiler (at my previous company)... here goes:

What the XML Serializer internally does is it creates a class (let's call it 'A') using System.Reflection.Emit that accepts the type you pass to it. Constructing such a class costs a lot of time relatively speaking, and are reusable since types don't change. Because of this, the constructed types are stored in a dictionary, e.g. it ends up with some Dictionary .

For known (basic) types, the serializer code is fixed, e.g. the serialization of a string is not going to change no matter how many times you restart your application. Note the difference with 'A' where any type that's unknown to the serialization factory till it's first passed to the XMLSerializer.

The first time the type is used by the XMLSerializer, this process takes place for both the type you pass and all types it needs (e.g. all fields and properties that require serialization).

About the leak... When you call the ChannelFactory, it constructs serializer if it doesn't exist yet. For that it checks if the serializer already exists in the Dictionary and if not, creates one by making an instance of ISomeSerializerType.

For some stupid reason, there is a bug in the factory that constructs a new serializer without storing it in the dictionary. Once constructed, you end up with a new type - which shows up as a leak (remember: types can never be unloaded) - even though the objects are correctly disposed. When you use XMLSerializer first or create a static class, it correctly uses the Dictionary cache, which means it won't leak. So there you have it, **it is a bug**. I used to have access to ANTS Memory Profiler, which showed this quite nicely.

Hope this explains.

Comment: This explains it and it also was my assumption, that something like this must be going on. Thanks for the detailed explanation. The cream on top would be to have some reference where the behavior is described of course...

Comment: Iirc it was hidden somewhere in the CreateChannel call. BTW: changing to singleton is not a good idea as well, see http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/03/31/creating-of-proxies-inside-of-singleton-service.aspx (not sure if it's related though).

Comment: From the reference you provided: "If this holds, then also proxy instances can be singletons too.". So if I understand correctly this is even the proposed solution - to use a single instance.

Comment: Must have been late, because yesterday I didn't notice. But you describe: "When you use XMLSerializer first or create a static class...". My problem is ONLY if I use XMLSerializer first. And only if I use it before instantiating WindowsService. If I had to speculate I'd say, that the XMLSerializer dictionary with custom types is somehow duplicated for each transactional call, and the custom type stays in memory after call is completed. LEAK. But this is what I wanted to clarify.

Comment: Actually that's what I meant, it's just not duplicated but recreated. Types are _always_ persistent in .NET. Regarding your first comment, using a single instance and storing it internally is what I do 99% of the time... To be honest, after digging through almost all the WCF code I personally consider it to be over-designed and just solve problems as they present themselves: I've seen many leaks and unexpected behaviors in the past years using WCF (the most interesting one was killing the network card of a production server when I forgot to use Dispose in a runtime generated proxy :-) ).

Answer (score 6):

The XmlSerializer documentation says this:

> To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies. This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:
>
> XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)
>
> XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)
>
> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: I am confused, I can't find any documentation that suggests an XmlSerializer<T> class exists.

Comment: @StampedeXV http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/15/net-memory-leak-xmlserializing-your-way-to-a-memory-leak.aspx Comments suggest it's a "problem" with WCF and you can either cache clients or use AppDomains to mitigate it.

Comment: thanks for the research. Using a cached client worked for us also, maybe I'll also try AppDomains. We also found an easy workaround, but what I'd really like to know is: what is the reason for this behavior.

Comment: This is because assemblies created dynamically by XmlSerializer cannot be unloaded (CLR does not allow this). You would have to unload the whole AppDomain

Comment: But why is it increasing the handles? XmlSerializer is initialized only once!

Comment: @StampedeXV I'll see if I can gain any insights from the WCF implementation, but your statement that "`XmlSerializer` is initialized only once!" is not correct -- `XmlSerializer` may be initialised may times by WCF or code.

Comment: Ok. Only once by me.  But that ifs beside the point. If I don't instantiate it before starting windows service it works. My question is about the reasons for this. I know how to avoid it, but what I would like to know isthe WHY.